# How to show image using smarty, when it is stored on amazon?

Tags: php, image, smarty

My images are stored on Amazon servers and I have to display them (using smarty) in a smarty template.
currently I am able to show an image using following PHP code:

```
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');  
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=\"".basename($formatted_filename)."\"");
```

How could I show it on smarty page?

Comment: I tried by using image tag and output from amazon as source.

Comment: Can you please add your attempts in your question? It's also not clear what kind of result you exactly want.

Comment: What smarty code have you tried? Do you have the URL to the image in your smarty template?

Answer (score 0):

You do it the same way you would do it in html

```
<img src="image_url" alt="whatever"/>
```

in your case the url of the image is the script you created in php, i.e. show_image.php?image_id=33